# Solr core Schema update : Master/slave setup

Tags: java, solr

What is the recommended procedure to upgrade a schema in solr core (In a master slave setup). I am looking to add 2 new fileds to my schema.

Can i update the schema in my master, without any issues in my replication. (And then eventually upgrade the schema in slaves). What is the recommended procedure to add fields in solr schema.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you've configured your master node to replicate the configuration files to the slave nodes, you only have to update the files on the master and everything should be handled automagically for you.

See the `confFiles` parameter below.

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler">
  <lst name="master">
    <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>
    <str name="backupAfter">optimize</str>
    <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,stopwords.txt,elevate.xml</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

You can also use this feature to have a central solrconfig (for example `solrconfig_slave.xml`) for your slaves, which is then replicated to your slaves under the actual name (`solrconfig.xml`) :

```
<str name="confFiles">solrconfig_slave.xml:solrconfig.xml,....</str>
```

As long as you have this configured, you should be able to just update your master schema.xml, reload the core (to make Solr notice the changes) and it'll be replicated to your client on the next commit.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. Do i need to restart my master or slaves (or both) post the schema change. Or are the schema changes auto-picked ?

Comment: You'll need to reload the core on the leader to make it pick up the changes to the schema file, but the follower should get it automagically when the next replication happens.